# Insert values to a previous table in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to insert values in a tabla with values inside, like this table:

[image]

If you look at the column "202001" and row 22 at the end, it is null, so I want to insert manually any value.
It is null because that value it's not inserted to the database yet.

The expression I have is Sum([SH_historico_1.MONTO]/1000000) (Mounts..)

Any ideas? maybe with that SUM and then concadenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Alt(Sum([SH_historico_1.MONTO]/1000000),0)
```

where 0 is as you say "any value".
ALt function return first numeric value. So when your function will not return any number, another number is used.